# Find $m$ such that $a^m \bmod c = x$ given $a^n \bmod b = x$

Tags: modular-arithmetic

Given

$$ a^n \bmod b = x,$$

how can we find $m$ such that

$$a^m \bmod c = x?$$

Edit: Alternatively, since we know $a$, $c$, and $x$, how you can solve for $m$ directly?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Is $c$ a divisor of $b$?

Comment: Not necessarily

Comment: Then it's not possible...?

Comment: Then you can't determine the remainder modulo $c$. The best you have is the remainder modulo $\gcd (b,c)$.

Comment: Are $a$, $b$, $c$ and $x$ given? Or are you looking for a general procedure?

Comment: Im looking for a general procedure

Comment: Even if you know $x$ and $c$ you have to solve $m \log a = \log x$ where all these are calculated modulo $c$. Now it is generally believed that find the $\log$ is difficult (many cryptographic schemes rely on this). You could always write the answer in terms of primitive roots of $c$.

Comment: Is it possible when you know $a$, $n$, $b$, $c$, and $x$?

Comment: So basically all the variables are constant except $m$ here?

Comment: If you know $a$, $c$ and $x$ you can determine those $m$ such that $a^m \mod c = x$ (e.g. by examining  $a^j \mod c$ for positive integers $j$ until you get $1$).  But $a^n \mod b$ is irrelevant to this.

Comment: @Ethan that is correct

Comment: @RobertIsrael I'm interested in finding a method other than observation.

Comment: @user44197 Then can't you just solve $a^m\equiv x \text{ mod } c$ directly using a discrete logarithm since you know both $a,x,c$?

Comment: How would I go about solving using a discrete logarithm?

Comment: Yes, then I don't see the point of $a^n\equiv x \mod b$. It is hard to tease out what is given and what is not.

Comment: @user117473 Where did you get this problem from?

Comment: @Ethan It is one I came up with on my own. I was simply curious about it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a *general* procedure for solving
$$
a^m \equiv x \mod c
$$
I will assume that $x$ and $c$ are co-prime and $r$ is primitive root of $c$, i.e
$$
r^{\phi(c)} \equiv 1 \mod c ~~\hbox{and} ~~ r^k \not \equiv 1 \mod c, ~1\le k < \phi(c)
$$
We can always find an $m$ so that $r^\alpha = x$. $\alpha$ is the discrete logarithm of $x$. 
Let $a = r^\beta$. Then the original equation becomes

$$ \left(r ^\beta\right)^m=r^\alpha \mod c$$

The solution to this is
$$
\beta m = \alpha \mod \phi(c)
$$

Hope this helps

Comment: But that procedure is not computationally effective in general since computing discrete logs is [notoriously difficult.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discrete_logarithm#Algorithms) Perhaps the OPs problem has further structure that makes it easier.

Comment: I agree! In one of my comments I said that the difficulty of computing discrete logarithms is the basis of many cryptographic system. However, he wanted a specific procedure and I don't know any general procedure than what I wrote.